# Trying to scrub 700 000 data against 15 million data

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to scrub 700 000 data obtained from single file, which need to be scrubbed against a data of 15 million present in multiple files.

Example: 1 file of 700 000 say A. Multiple files pool which have 15 million call it B.
I want a pool B of files with no data of file A.

Below is the shell script I am trying to use it is working fine. But it is taking massive time of more than 8 Hours in scrubbing.

```
IFS=$'\r\n' suppressionArray=($(cat abhinav.csv1))
suppressionCount=${#suppressionArray[@]}
cd /home/abhinav/01-01-2015/
for (( j=0; j<$suppressionCount; j++));
do
   arrayOffileNameInWhichSuppressionFound=`grep "${suppressionArray[$j]},"  *.csv| awk -F ':' '{print $1}' > /home/abhinav/fileNameContainer.txt`
    IFS=$'\r\n' arrayOffileNameInWhichSuppressionFound=($(cat /home/abhinav/fileNameContainer.txt))
    arrayOffileNameInWhichSuppressionFoundCount=${#arrayOffileNameInWhichSuppressionFound[@]}
    if [ $arrayOffileNameInWhichSuppressionFoundCount -gt 0 ];
    then
        echo -e "${suppressionArray[$j]}" >> /home/abhinav/emailid_Deleted.txt
        for (( k=0; k<$arrayOffileNameInWhichSuppressionFoundCount; k++));
        do
            sed  "/^${suppressionArray[$j]}/d" /home/abhinav/06-07-2015/${arrayOffileNameInWhichSuppressionFound[$k]} > /home/abhinav/06-07-2015/${arrayOffileNameInWhichSuppressionFound[$i]}".tmp" && mv -f /home/abhinav/06-07-2015/${arrayOffileNameInWhichSuppressionFound[$i]}".tmp" /home/abhinav/06-07-2015/${arrayOffileNameInWhichSuppressionFound[$i]}

       done
     fi
done
```

Another solution clicked in my mind is to breakdown 700k data into smaller size files of 50K and send across 5-available servers, also POOL A will be available at each server.
Each server will serve for 2-Smaller file.

Comment: This is a demonstration of why names like 'a' and 'n' have some advantages; the names you're using are so long that it is hard to read, not least because you can't fit everything on a single line without horizontal scrolling.  You should have the name fragment `/home/abhinav/06-07-2015` in a variable and use that instead of repeating yourself.  You should seriously consider using 2015-07-06 for the 6th of July 2015; it sorts the directories in date order by default, which is often helpful. (It's curious you start off in `/home/abhinav/01-01-2015` even though you're working on data elsewhere.)

Comment: Can you show some some sample data from input files with your expected output.

Comment: @anubhava: AFAICT, the file `abhinav.csv1` contains about 700k lines with patterns in them.  The objective is to edit an indeterminate number of CSV files (`*.csv`) which have some 15M lines in them in total.  The editing consists of removing any occurrence of a line containing the data from one of the lines in `abhinav.csv1` followed by a comma.  There's an assumption that the lines in `abhinav.csv1` will not contain slashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two lines are peculiar:

```
arrayOffileNameInWhichSuppressionFound=`grep "${suppressionArray[$j]},"  *.csv| awk -F ':' '{print $1}' > /home/abhinav/fileNameContainer.txt`
IFS=$'\r\n' arrayOffileNameInWhichSuppressionFound=($(cat /home/abhinav/fileNameContainer.txt))
```

The first assigns an empty string to the mile-long variable name because the standard output is directed to the file.  The second then reads that file into the array.  ('Tis curious that the name is not `arrayOfFileNameInWhichSuppressionFound`, but the lower-case `f` for `file` is consistent, so I guess it doesn't matter beyond making it harder to read the variable name.)

That could be reduced to:

```
ArrFileNames=( $(grep -l "${suppressionArray[$j]}," *.csv) )
```

You shouldn't need to keep futzing with carriage returns in IFS; either set it permanently, or make sure there are no carriage returns before you start.

---

You're running these loops 7,00,000 times (using the Indian notation).  That's a lot.  No wonder it is taking hours.  You need to group things together.

You should probably simply take the lines from `abhinav.csv1` and arrange to convert them into appropriate `sed` commands, and then split them up and apply them.  Along the lines of:

```
sed 's%.*%/&,/d%' abhinav.csv1 > names.tmp
split -l 500 names.tmp sed-script.

for script in sed-script.*
do
    sed -f "$script" -i.bak *.csv
done
```

This uses the `-i` option to backup the files.  It may be necessary to do redirection explicitly if your `sed` does not support the `-i` option:

```
    for file in *.csv
    do
        sed -f "$script" "$file" > "$file.tmp" &&
        mv "$file.tmp" "$file"
    done
```

You should experiment to see how big the scripts can be.  I chose 500 in the `split` command as a moderate compromise.  Unless you're on antique HP-UX, that should be safe, but you may be able to increase the size of the script more, which will reduce the number of times you have to edit each file, which speeds up the processing.  If you can use 5,000 or 50,000, you should do so.  Experiment to see what the upper limit.  I'm not sure that you'd find doing all 700,000 lines at once is feasible — but it should be fastest if you can do it that way.